# How to get rid of the this warning: "Warning: validateDOMNesting(...)"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a functional component in my react app:
https://gist.github.com/andreisamoila74/bca55271c3992c079eed018e5c95a1be
And these are the warnings:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `ViewCode`
    in Fragment
    in ViewCode (at App.js:87)
    in Route (at App.js:86)
    in Switch (at App.js:72)
    in main (created by Basic)
    in Basic (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Content (at App.js:71)
    in section (created by Context.Consumer)
    in BasicLayout (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Layout (at App.js:68)
    in App (at src/index.js:13)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:12)
    in Suspense (at src/index.js:11)
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
    in tr (at View.js:49)
    in div (at View.js:48)
    in tbody (at View.js:93)
    in table (at View.js:92)
    in section (created by Context.Consumer)
    in BasicLayout (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Layout (at View.js:91)
    in div (at View.js:90)
    in ViewCode (at App.js:87)
    in Route (at App.js:86)
    in Switch (at App.js:72)
    in main (created by Basic)
    in Basic (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Content (at App.js:71)
    in section (created by Context.Consumer)
    in BasicLayout (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Layout (at App.js:68)
    in App (at src/index.js:13)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:12)
    in Suspense (at src/index.js:11)
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>.
    in div (at View.js:48)
    in tbody (at View.js:93)
    in table (at View.js:92)
    in section (created by Context.Consumer)
    in BasicLayout (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Layout (at View.js:91)
    in div (at View.js:90)
    in ViewCode (at App.js:87)
    in Route (at App.js:86)
    in Switch (at App.js:72)
    in main (created by Basic)
    in Basic (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Content (at App.js:71)
    in section (created by Context.Consumer)
    in BasicLayout (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Layout (at App.js:68)
    in App (at src/index.js:13)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:12)
    in Suspense (at src/index.js:11)
```

I understand each warning, but I am not sure how I can get rid of its. Regarding the table, I need those divs so my AddComment component is placed in the right way. How should I solve this? Thanks :)

Comment: `<tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>`  and `<div> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>` clearly showing where are the warnings and how to solve them

Answer (score 1):

The react keys need to be declared on the ***outer-most*** element mapped. In your case, the `Fragment`, or rather, the `div` since the `Fragment` isn't doing much for you.

The second error: "validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of " is saying the `tr` can't be a child of the `div`.

You can still use a `Fragment` though for both the purpose of returning a single node ***and*** provide the react key.

```
data.code.source_code.split("\n").forEach((line, index) => {
  rows.push(
    <Fragment key={index}> // <-- attach react key to Fragment
      <tr className="line">
        <td className="line-number">{index + 1}</td>
        <td id={"plus" + index} className="plus-square-line">
          <PlusSquareTwoTone
            className="plus-square"
            onClick={() => toggleLineCommentStatus(index + 1)}
          />
        </td>
        <td
          id={"codeblock" + index}
          className={"language-" + codeLanguage}
          style={rowStyle}
        >
          {line}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <div style={divStyle}>
        {lineComments[index + 1] ? (
          <AddComment
            id={id}
            lineNumber={index + 1}
            onCancelLineCommentShow={toggleLineCommentStatus}
          />
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array of children, like on row 46, each of them need to have a `key` prop.

If you don't have it, there is no way for React to know how the new and the old arrays are different, so it has to rerender all children, which is a performance drag. With `key` prop, it checks for new or deleted children by comparing keys from the new and old arrays of children.

You can read about it here https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
rows.push(
  <React.Fragment key={index}>
    <tr key={index} className="line">
      <td className="line-number">{index + 1}</td>
      <td id={"plus" + index} className="plus-square-line">
        <PlusSquareTwoTone className="plus-square"
          onClick={() => toggleLineCommentStatus(index + 1)} />
      </td>
      <td id={"codeblock" + index}
        className={'language-' + codeLanguage} style={rowStyle}>
        {line}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        {lineComments[index + 1]
          ?
          <AddComment
            id={id}
            lineNumber={index + 1}
            onCancelLineCommentShow={toggleLineCommentStatus}
          />
          :
          null
        }
      </td>
    </tr>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

thanks for answers